# Is conversion int -> unsigned long long defined by the standard

Tags: c++, type-conversion, standards

I can't find the exact specification of how `int` value is converted to `unsigned long long` in the standard. Various similar conversions, such as int -> unsigned, unsigned -> int (UB if negative), unsigned long long -> int, etc. are specified

For example GCC, `-1` is converted to `0xffffffffffffffff`, not to `0x00000000ffffffff`. Can I rely on this behavior?

Comment: That looks like sign extending: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_extension So probably yes

Comment: There are two possibilities: 1) conversion to `long long` and then to `unsigned long long`; 2) conversion to `unsigned` and the to `unsigned long long`. It's not obvious which takes precedence by the letter of the standard.

Comment: @user12: the way that it's done is neither of your two possibilies, but a very direction conversion from `int` to `unsigned long long`. If the latter is larger (as it usually is) then on an ordinary machine with two's complement representation of signed integer values, sign extension is performed. Sign extension consists of simply replicating the most significant bit (the sign bit) to fill out left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is well defined, it is basically adding `max unsigned long long + 1` to `-1` which will always be `max unsigned long long`. This is covered in the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `4.7` *Integral conversions* which says:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type). [ Note: In a two’s complement representation, this conversion is conceptual and there is no change in the bit pattern (if there is no truncation). —end note ]

it does the same thing as C99 but the [draft C99 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) is easier to understand, from section `6.3.1.3` *Signed and unsigned integers*:

> Otherwise, if the new type is unsigned, the value is converted by repeatedly adding or
>   subtracting one more than the maximum value that can be represented in the new type
>   until the value is in the range of the new type.<sup>49)</sup>

where footnote `49` says:

> The rules describe arithmetic on the mathematical value, not the value of a given type of expression.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's defined:

C++11 § 4.7 [conv.integral]/2 says this:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>n</sup> where n is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

The least unsigned integer congruent to -1 (modulo 2<sup>`sizeof(unsigned long long)`</sup>) is the largest value of `unsigned long long` possible.

Answer (score 1):

Unsigned integers have guaranteed modulo arithmetic. Thus any `int` value *v* is converted to the `unsigned long` value *u* such that *u* = K*2<sup>*n*</sup>+*v*, where K is either 0 or 1, and  where *n* is the number of value representation bits for `unsigned long`. In other words, if *v* is negative, just add 2<sup>*n*</sup>.

---

The power of 2 follows from the C++ standard's requirement that integers be represented with a pure binary system. With *n* value representation bits the number of possible values is 2<sup>*n*</sup>. There is not such a requirement for floating point types (you can use `std::numeric_limits` to check the radix of the representation of floating point values).

---

Also note that in order to cater to some now archaic platforms, as well as one popular compiler that does things its own way, the standard leaves the opposite conversion as undefined behavior when the unsigned value is not directly representable as a signed value. In practice, on modern systems all compilers can be told to make that reverse conversion the exact opposite of the conversion to unsigned type, and e.g. Visual C++ does that by default. However, it's worth keeping in mind that there's no formal support, so that portable code incurs a slight (now with modern computers needless) inefficiency.

Comment: `k` can in theory be something besides 0 or 1 if the `unsigned` value is smaller -- but `long` and `long long` are not going to be smaller than `int`.  As an aside, I swore that something changed/was clarified recently here wrt `int` types larger than `int`...

Comment: @Yakk: yes, with other types involved you can have other (integral) K values. Re clarification, I don't think it was me. I remember some years ago someone asked about ranges for built-in types and I referred them to C standard. That incurred the wrath of the kid, who refused to believe that anything in the C standard could apply to C++. Or maybe he/they wanted me to do the legwork of finding and quoting the relevant passages. He or they also refused to believe that powers of 2 could have anything to do with number ranges. It was sort of unpleasant.

Comment: I mean, I thought there was a bug in C/C++ wrt integer types larger than `int` or `long` that was fixed recently (like C++11 or the like)

Comment: @Yakk: no, not a bug exactly, but C++03 did not support `long long` since C++03 was just a technical correction of C++98, which came before C99 (where `long long` was introduced). C++11 is based on C99, and thus does have `long long`. C++11 also has C99's `<stdint.h>`, but unfortunately in the haste to get C++11 standardized the list of supported C headers has three different counts of them :-) (that's fixed now, but I don't think that's what you're referring to). Oh, and the result of division and remainder with negative arguments is now well-defined, rounding towards 0.