# backward loop with size_t loop variable

Tags: c++

Is the following code defined behavior, I mean i-- when i is 0 will always be  the biggest unsigned int representable by size_t, right ? so is this totally safe to use it in my code ?

```
size_t NPOS = -1;
for(size_t i = vec.size()-1; i!= NPOS; i--)
```

Comment: Provided your platform uses 2's complement to represent signed integers, yes.

Comment: @heinrichj, It still has to work in 1's complement as well. See C++11 § 4.7 [conv.integral]/2. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131388/is-conversion-int-unsigned-long-long-defined-by-the-standard) might also be of some interest.

Comment: Use `i-->0` instead: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1642028/what-is-the-name-of-this-operator

Comment: You know that vector has reverse iterators to do that?

Comment: @dalle Why?  To obfuscate, or ?

Comment: @JamesKanze: On the contrary, to unobfuscate. If find it easier to read `for(size_t i = vec.size(); i-- > 0;)` or `size_t i = vec.size(); while(i-- > 0)` than using the `NPOS` approach.

Comment: @dalle What `NPOS` approach?  If a condition has side effects, it's obfuscation.  A reader who sees a `while` doesn't look for side effects.  A reader doesn't expect side effects in the second part of a `for` either.  (The more or less standard way for writing this sort of loop, assuming no reverse iterators, would be `while ( i > 0 ) { --i; /* ... */ }`.  At least in the code I've seen.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In class `std::basic_string` static data member `npos` is defined the following way

```
static const size_type npos = -1;
```

Take into account that the type of the return value of member function `size()` is `size_type`. So your code is valid

```
size_t NPOS = -1;
for(size_t i = vec.size()-1; i!= NPOS; i--)
```

provided that the value of expression `vec.size()-1`can be stored in type `size_t`

so the more valid code will look as

```
for ( std::vector<T>::size_type i = vec.size()-1; i != std::vector<T>::npos; i-- )
```

Though I would write the loop the following way

```
for ( std::vector<T>::size_type i = vec.size(); i != 0;  )
{
   //...
   // using expression vec[--i]
   // or
   //  --i
   // vec[i]
   //...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a classic scenario for using the fabulous goes-to operator:

```
for (size_t i = vec.size(); i --> 0; )
```

Answer (score 1):

Technically, it works, since the converion of `-1` to an
unsigned type is guaranteed to result in the largest possible
value, as is decrementing from `0`.  Still, it's not what
I would consider good practice.  If you just want to iterate
over one vector in reverse:

```
for ( auto current = vec.rbegin(); current != vec.rend(); ++ current ) {
    //      Do something with *current
}
```

And if for some reason you do need the index:

```
int i = vec.size();
while ( i != 0 ) {
    -- i;
    //      Do something with vec[i]
}
```

This loop is much cleaner, and avoids any issues with unsigned
types wrapping (although if you need the index, that probably
means you need it as an arithmetic value, so you should avoid
unsigned types to begin with).

Answer (score 0):

All of these will be the same value for a given integer type `T`, signed or unsigned:

```
T a = -1;
T b = 0 - 1;
T c = 0; c = c - 1;
T d = 0; d --;
T e = 0; -- e;

assert(a == b);
assert(a == c);
assert(a == d);
assert(a == e);
```

That covers all of the usages you have in your snippet. The internal representation of the integer doesn't really matter. The fact that a signed -1 converts to the maximum value of a similar unsigned integer is interesting but not directly significant. The above is true else arithmetic stops working.