# Signed to unsigned conversion in C++

Tags: c++, integer, standards, c++14, signed

In C++, does the result of the conversion of a signed integral value, to an unsigned integral value, that can be of two different sizes (ex: `short int` to `unsigned long long int`, or `long long int` to `unsigned char`) is well defined by the standard and platform independent (regardless of how signed integer are represented for example)?

Comment: You can do a char to an int. And the former is just as easy. Otherwise use `long long int x=static_cast<long long int> y`

Comment: Yes it is see [Is conversion int -> unsigned long long defined by the standard](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22131388/1708801)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the value is defined and independent of the representations used. [conv.integral]/2:

> If the destination type is unsigned, the resulting value is the least
>   unsigned integer congruent to the source integer (modulo 2<sup>*n*</sup> where *n*
>   is the number of bits used to represent the unsigned type).

Obviously, the size of the destination type matters, though; `long long` to `unsigned char` might yield a different value than `long long` to `unsigned int`.